# How to dynamically generate nested loop based on loop variables

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I'm building a test program. this program will iterate a lot of parameters combination and return test result for every case.
My question is that it is not all types of parameters are sent into program. For example, Param A, Param B, and Param C come in this time. then I'll make 3 loops for all parameter combinations:

```
foreach (var a in paramA )
   foreach (var b in paramB )
       foreach (var c in paramC )
```

But sometimes there are ParamA, ParamD, or then I have to make loops like the following

```
foreach ( var a in paramA )
   foreach ( var d in paramD )
```

So I wonder if there's a certain design pattern or technique for this particular problem

Thanks

Comment: It seems like you want recursion?

Comment: are these params of the same type?? if so why don't you pass  an array of params

Comment: @GaganDeep no..all kinds of types including class objects and structs...

Comment: @John  I thought about that. But different type of parameter requires different action, i don't know how to put them in one recursive function. Use case statement?

Comment: May be you can write a single function and use C# reflection to get the type of your current param in a loop and do the action based on the type in a case statement.

Comment: If you can post a more concrete example it would help. For running different action, I would say a dictionary having object type as key and an action/func as the value would help. For iterating loops some sort of reflection trick should help, but again a more concrete example would be great.

Answer (score 0):

This is my recursion attempt.

Assuming `var[] pars` is the array contains all the param.

```
private void RunAll(var[] parm)
{
    foreach(var p in parm[0])
    {
        //Do something.
        if(parm.Count()>1) RunAll(parm.Skip(1).ToArray());
        else
        {
            //Do something for the bottom-most param.
        }
    }
}
```

And in the main code, simply put all the param in `pars` and call `RunAll(pars);`

Good luck!